# How can be array elements multiplied with big O(n)

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I have an array which it has N number.I would like to multiply array element as the following rule;

```
arr[n]={5,7,2,3,4....}

the first row:A[0]*A[2]*A[3]*A[4]....*A[n]
the second row:A[0]*A[1]*A[3]*A[4]....*A[n]
the third row:A[0]*A[1]*A[2]*A[4]...*A[n]
...........
the n row:A[0]*A[1]*A[2]*A[3]*A[4]....*A[n-1]
```

i did it with O(n^2) but i couldn't solve it O(n) how can i do that without division row element ?

Comment: It's possible to copy the row result to another array but the point is that array elements must be multiplied with each other with O(n).

Comment: If division is not allowed then I'm sure getting people on the internet to solve this for you is also not allowed.

Comment: what is wrong my question if i could that without division i wouldn't ask.

Comment: What Lightness Races in Orbit is trying to say (and I agree) is that you are supposed to solve your own homework. Clearly aren't supposed to ask SO (or other websites) to solve the problem for you. With or without restrictions.

Comment: You are right it's an homework but i couldn't solve it and how do i learn it without asking ? I studied on it all day and lastly i had to ask it!Please don't be prejudicious

Comment: I think there is an issue with the indices: If `N` is the number of elements and you start your indices with `0`, you should not use `N` as an index into your array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming no zeros in the array, a possible approach could be

```
product = A[0]*...*A[n]
first = product / A[1]
second = product / A[2]
....
```

---

If division is not allowed, you can utilize left and right running products and do something like this:

```
int P[N], Q[N];
P[0] = A[0];
for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
    P[i] = P[i - 1] * A[i];
Q[N-1] = A[N-1]; 
for(int i = N-2; i >= 0; --i)
    Q[i] = Q[i+1] * A[i];

for(int i = 1; ....)
    R[i] = P[i-1] * Q[i+1];
```

Comment: sorry but the division is not allowed

Comment: I dont't know you can ask it to my lecturer :)

Comment: No thanks. We'd rather stick to real-world solutions to problems instead of succumbing to arbitrary restrictions that rule out the best and cleverest solutions.

Comment: @Archangel Then you can  multiply left and right running products. I updated the answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The division method is not the best and cleverest solution. Any current processor takes an awful long time to do a division, so the well arranged multiplication is probably about five times faster.

Comment: @gnasher729: _"Any current processor takes an awful long time to do a division"_ Nonsense!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we don't overflow and that there are no zeroes.

```
std::array<int, n> arr = {5, 7, 2, 3, 4, ...};
int total = 1;

for (int v : arr)
    total *= v;
for (int & v : arr)
    v = total / v;
```

Comment: the division is not allowed!

Answer (score 2):

You've got two answers that rely on a mathematical trick.

I would concentrate on what work is actually required. Take a look at the first and second calculation. You calculate both doing about 2n products. But look at which numbers you are multiplying: These two calculation have an awful lot in common. It should be obvious how to calculate both using only about n products.

Once you've got that idea, you should be able to calculate all the results you want with about 3n multiplications and without any division. I'll write your calculation just a little bit different:

```
For the first row: (A[0]) * (A[2]*A[3]*A[4]....*A[n])
For the second row:(A[0]*A[1]) * (A[3]*A[4]....*A[n])
For the third row: (A[0]*A[1]*A[2]) * (A[4]...*A[n])
```

How do you calculate all the left parentheses doing n multiplications? How do you calculate all the right parentheses doing n multiplications?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean sorry bro!